# Azure Blob Storage : DownloadToStreamAsync downloading 0kb streams

Tags: c#, azure

Looking at my code below, I am amazed with the amount of boilerplate code I am required to write just to ensure that a library downloads a file correctly.

Are there any reason why I see 0kb downloaded streams or is this just normal to write a method like this?

```
 public static async Task<string> DownloadSASUriInputDataAsync(string workingDirectory, string sasUri)
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("{0}", sasUri);
        var input = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(sasUri));
        input.ServiceClient.DefaultRequestOptions.RetryPolicy = new ExponentialRetry(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), 10);

        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(input.Name);

        await Retry.LinearAsync(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await input.DownloadToStreamAsync(ms);
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    if (ms.Length == 0)
                    {
                        throw new RunAlgorithmException("Downloaded file was 0 byte");
                    }

                    using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(workingDirectory, fileName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        await ms.CopyToAsync(fs);
                    }
                }

                Trace.TraceInformation("downloaded file");

            }
            catch (StorageException ex)
            {

                Trace.TraceError("Failed to DownloadSASUriInputDataAsync : {0}", ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500),10);

        return fileName;
    }
```

Comment: Well, use DownloadToFile and delete 90% of your code.

Comment: DownloadToFile creates the file even though the stream is 0 bytes. no reason to create it before its needed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with all the 0kb streams was that the blobs was still being copied.

Blobs can still be accessed even though they are being copied and it will give the behavior above.

Adding checks before tryingto download that the blob.CopyState is completed or missing ensures that it work as the SLA states.